# Are there any restrictions in writing multiple http responses?

Tags: http, proxy, netty, pipelining

I am building a [HTTP proxy](https://github.com/JHK/jLange) with netty, which supports HTTP pipelining. Therefore I receive multiple `HttpRequest` Objects on a single Channel and got the matching `HttpResponse` Objects. The order of the `HttpResponse` writes is the same than I got the `HttpRequest`. If a `HttpResponse` was written, the next one will be written when the `HttpProxyHandler` receives a `writeComplete` event.

The Pipeline should be convenient:

```
final ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("writer", new HttpResponseWriteDelayHandler());
pipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentCompressor(9));
pipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpProxyHandler());
```

Regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082101/do-messages-sent-via-nettys-channel-write-preserve-their-order-when-begin-sen) only the order of the write calls should be important, but to be sure I build another Handler (`HttpResponseWriteDelayHandler`) which suppresses the `writeComplete` event until the whole response was written.

To test this I enabled `network.http.proxy.pipelining` in Firefox and visited a page with many images and connections ([a news page](http://www.spiegel.de)). The problem is, that the browser does not receive some responses in spite of the logs of the proxy consider them as sent successfully.

I have some findings:

- The problem only occurs if the connection from proxy to server is faster than the connection from proxy to browser.
- The problem occurs more often after sending a larger image on that connection, e.g. 20kB
- The problem does not occur if only `304 - Not Modified` responses were sent (refreshing the page considering browser cache)
- Setting `bootstrap.setOption("sendBufferSize", 1048576);` or above does not help
- Sleeping a timeframe dependent on the responses body size in before sending the `writeComplete` event in `HttpResponseWriteDelayHandler` solves the problem, but is a very bad solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and want to share it, if anyone else has a similar problem:

The content of the `HttpResponse` is too big. To analyze the content the whole HTML document was in the buffer. This must be splitted in Chunks again to send it properly. If the `HttpResponse` is not chunked I wrote a simple solution to do it. One needs to put a `ChunkedWriteHandler` next to the logic handler and write this class instead of the response itself:

```
public class ChunkedHttpResponse implements ChunkedInput {

    private final static int       CHUNK_SIZE = 8196;
    private final HttpResponse     response;
    private final Queue<HttpChunk> chunks;
    private boolean                isResponseWritten;

    public ChunkedHttpResponse(final HttpResponse response) {
        if (response.isChunked())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("response must not be chunked");

        this.chunks = new LinkedList<HttpChunk>();
        this.response = response;
        this.isResponseWritten = false;

        if (response.getContent().readableBytes() > CHUNK_SIZE) {
            while (CHUNK_SIZE < response.getContent().readableBytes()) {
                chunks.add(new DefaultHttpChunk(response.getContent().readSlice(CHUNK_SIZE)));
            }
            chunks.add(new DefaultHttpChunk(response.getContent().readSlice(response.getContent().readableBytes())));
            chunks.add(HttpChunk.LAST_CHUNK);

            response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.EMPTY_BUFFER);
            response.setChunked(true);
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.TRANSFER_ENCODING, HttpHeaders.Values.CHUNKED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNextChunk() throws Exception {
        return !isResponseWritten || !chunks.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Object nextChunk() throws Exception {
        if (!isResponseWritten) {
            isResponseWritten = true;
            return response;
        } else {
            HttpChunk chunk = chunks.poll();
            return chunk;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfInput() throws Exception {
        return isResponseWritten && chunks.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}
}
```

Then one can call just `channel.write(new ChunkedHttpResponse(response)` and the chunking is done automatically if needed.